# Ember controller computed property (of type Object) update doesnt work

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to combine sorting properties (`sortProperties` and `sortAscending`) with filters on a list of data.

I have an `ArrayController` and two actions, one for sorting and one for filters. Filter action sets properties on `filters` object, but property that depends on `filters` is not re-calucalted.

Relevant controller code:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  filters: Ember.Object.create({}),
  filteredContent: function () {
    var ret = this.get('arrangedContent');
    Object.keys(this.filters).forEach(function (name) {
      ret = ret.filter(this.filters.get(name));
    }, this);
    return ret;
  // I expect this to cause `filteredContent` to depend on `filters` property
  }.property('arrangedContent', 'filters'),

  actions: {
    sort: function(property, isSorted) {
      this.set('sortProperties', [property]);
      if (isSorted) {
        this.toggleProperty('sortAscending');
      } else {
        this.set('sortAscending', true); 
      }
    },
    filter: function (property, value) {
      var filters = this.get('filters');
      switch (property) {
        case 'id':
          // I expect that call to `set` would trigger `filteredContent` property update
          filters.get('id') || filters.set('id', function (post) {
            return post.get('id') < value;
          });
          break;
        case 'title':
          filters.get('title') || filters.set('title', function (post) {
            return post.get('title').indexOf(value) !== -1;
          });
          break;
      }

    }
  }
});
```

So, my question is why `filters.set()` doesn’t cause `filteredContent` function to run?

All code is here – http://jsbin.com/silun/7/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @torazaburo not sure I understand your question – I want `filteredContent` to rerender when `filters` object has a property changed (added, updated or removed).

Comment: @torazaburo oh, that, sure, updated the jsbin. But the problem is that the filteredContent function is not even ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating properties on the `filters` object, so you need to observe the specific object attributes you are changing.

You can do this by explicitly listing the attributes to depend on:

```
filteredContent: function () {
  //...
}.property('arrangedContent', 'filters.id', 'filters.title'),
```

or by using a shorthand notation called [property brace expansion](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/02/12/ember-1-4-0-and-ember-1-5-0-beta-released.html#toc_property-brace-expansion).

```
filteredContent: function () {
  //...
}.property('arrangedContent', 'filters.{id,title}'),
```

Updated JSBin: http://jsbin.com/nuyegowede/1/edit

### Update

new JSBin with `filters` as array: http://jsbin.com/yayihazoza/1/edit

If you want unlimited filter attributes without updating the computed property you can use a configure `filters` as an array instead of an object. This lets you use Ember's array observer features ([@each](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) to automatically update the filtering when the array changes.

`filters` is now an array of filter objects that are in this form:

```
   {
     name: 'name-of-filter',
     filter: function(){
       // implementation of filter here
     }
   }
```

update `filter` to push the filter objects into the `filters` array:

```
filter: function (property, value) {
      var filters = this.get('filters');
      console.log("filter", property, value);
      
      switch (property) {
        case 'id':
          if (filters.findBy('name', 'id') === undefined) {
            filters.pushObject({
              name: 'id',
              filter: function (post) {
                return (post.get('id') < value);
              }
            });
          }
          break;
        case 'title':
          if (filters.findBy('name', 'title') === undefined) {
            filters.pushObject({
              name: 'title',
              filter: function (post) {
                return post.get('title').indexOf(value) !== -1;
              }
            });
          }
          break;
      }
      
    }
```

update the computed property to use the new filter objects and also to listen for changes to each item in the array

```
  filteredContent: function () {
    var ret = this.get('arrangedContent');
    var filters = this.get('filters');

    filters.forEach(function (filterObj) {
      ret = ret.filter(filterObj.filter);
    }, this);
    return ret;
  }.property('arrangedContent', 'filters.@each'), // <-- notice the new @each
```

Comment: thank a lot for your answer! what if I wanted to watch for an unlimited list of attributes (all of them)?

Comment: There is no way to watch every attribute without explicitly declaring it or setting up the observers yourself, unless you write your own observable object class.

Comment: @gryzzly you could change how you define your filters to a way that ember could observe automatically, like putting individual filter objects in an array, which is then observed.

Comment: @c4p I tried exactly the same with array, didn't work :( here's Array based version http://jsbin.com/pewizemova/2/edit?js,output

Comment: hey, that's cool! I think `'filters.[]'` will actually suffice – `@each` watches properties and it's good enough if property recomputes on add/delete from array.

Comment: This will let me do what I want, although I still wonder why can't we watch an object, if it uses `set` – shouldn't be a performance problem.